# Alamofire, Swift: What could be causing this error?

Tags: swift, alamofire

What could be causing this error?

All of a sudden out of nowhere I started getting the error below. I have reinstalled the cocoapod, cleaned the build folder, and reinstalled the app already and none of that has fixed the error.

**ERROR:** Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

**CODE:**

```
let recoverUrl = "http://www.website.com/recover.php?email=\(emailData)&local=application"

let urlEncodedString = recoverUrl.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "%20")

parseRecover(url: urlEncodedString)
```

//////////////

```
func parseRecover(url : String){ AF.request(url).responseJSON(completionHandler: { response in self.parseData(JSONData: response.data!) }) }

func parseData(JSONData : Data){

do {

 var readableJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: JSONData, options: .mutableContainers) as! JSONObject

if let recoverJSON = readableJSON["Recover"] as? [JSONObject] {

for i in 0..<recoverJSON.count {

let JSON = recoverJSON[i]

let status = JSON["status"] as! String

let message = JSON["message"] as! String

if status == "Error" {self.Alert01("\(message)")}

else if status == "Success" { self.Alert02("\(message)") }

}}}

catch { print(error) }

}
```

**ERROR IS OCCURING AT:**

```
func parseRecover(url : String){ AF.request(url).responseJSON(completionHandler: { response in self.parseData(JSONData: response.data!) }) }
```

Comment: I usually figure things out on my own but the reason I asked this question is because I don't think it has anything to do with my code. I have another app with the exact same code and it works fine. Just seeing if anyone had a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

There's no guarantee that a response has data, so force unwrapping the value can lead to crashes. I suggest you create `Decodable` types to parse your responses and use Alamofire's `responseDecodable` method to handle your responses.

Additionally, even if you don't adopt `Decodable`, `responseJSON` already parses your response `Data` using `JSONSerialization`, so you can just access the `response.result` to see the output.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED:** The issue was within my php file. I was using $_GET[''] and it should have been a $_POST[''] or $_REQUEST['']